# Why does lord Shiva have three eyes?

Tags: shiva, shaivism

How did lord Shiva of the Thrimoorthi get three eyes? Who gave him the third eye?

Comment: *Who gave him the third eye?* I don't think anyone gave him the third eye

Comment: Then how he got the third eye Mr.Alien? Please share your knowledge if you can.

Comment: Almost all Hindu deities have the third eye. It is believed that all our Gods and Goddesses are "Trikalagnya", i. e. they are completely aware of the past, present and future of the universe. This omniscience is reflected by the third eye.

Comment: All have given wrong answers for the third eye of mahadev. >omkar ne janam diya Meaning omkar gave birth to brahma vishnu and mahesh. One day their mother ahdhi shakthi decided to continue the birth process and asked if any of the sons could marry her. she had a third eye ,and lord shiva knowing that this is not correct as a deity. he told adhi shakthi to give him her third eye and he would marry her.she gave lord shiva the third eye and then lord shiva destroyed her since a mother cannot marry a son. this is how mahadev got his third eyes. its the eyes of destruction.

Comment: Lord Vishnu gave Lord Shiva the eye which is placed on his forehead....
a story is known as: when Vishnu worshiping Shiva, Vishnu suddenly realizes that one lotus flower is missing. Then to complete his oath to Shiva, Vishnu cut his eye out and donate it to Shiva. For this reason, Shiva placed the worshiped Eye of Vishnu to his forehead and gave Vishnu the Sudarshan Chakra. A Divine and unparalleled love between a Bhakt and Bhagavan.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The third eye as seen on Lord Shiva's forehead is also the **spiritual eye or ajna chakra** which stands for higher consciousness and allows us to see the real world for the world as we see it is an illusion.

Hindus believe that every human possesses this **'third eye'** which can be activated only after years of meditation.

**Who gave him the third eye?**

Shiva formed it himself.
According to Mahabharata, One day Shiva's wife Parvati, daughter of the King of Mountains, stealthily went behind Shiva and playfully placed her hands over his eyes. Suddenly darkness engulfed the whole world and all beings trembled in great fear as the lord of the universe had closed his eyes. Suddenly a massive eye of flame erupted from the forehead of Shiva; a third eye had appeared there and this gave light to the world.

However, this narration has a background to it. Shiva opened his third eye for the first time to set ablaze **Kama**, *the God of desire* when Kama tried to play cupid between Shiva and Parvati.
Since then it has been said that third eye is meant only for destruction.

A detailed and plausible background to this narration is found [here](http://devdutt.com/articles/indian-mythology/the-third-eye.html).

**What does it signify?**

Shiva’s third eye represents the rejection of desire. It is the eye that killed Kama. 
And why does Shiva reject desire? Because he realized the consequences of desire – when the object of desire (Sati) goes away, there is immense sorrow and rage. Desire not only evokes positive emotions (love, affection, contentment, compassion), it also evokes negative emotions (anger, dissatisfaction, sorrow). Shiva therefore shies away from it, preferring the cold still mountains which represent the state of transcendence – where there is just stillness, silence and bliss.

Comment: NO!!!, Shiva didn't formed third eye himself.

Comment: Shiva himself is Parmeshwara, nobody gave him this eye. The third eye is the sign of his supreme divine. +1 to this answer.

Comment: @pratik `Hindus believe that every human possesses this 'third eye' which can be activated only after years of meditation.` than do someone else had also possessed this `third eye`??,  as we have read in the books that there were many sages/devas/raksasha who were doing years and years of meditations that time...

Comment: @Nishant, There were people in past who had 3 eyes, eg, Sage Bhrigu is said to possess a third eye in his foot which was said to be the cause of his anger. Later, Lord Vishnu trickfully destroyed the third eye. This story is related to Tirupati Balaji. Apart from that, Nandi, Lord Shiva's gana is said to have 3 eyes, we also see in pictures sometimes that Goddess Kali also have a third eye. Don't know whether this is scripted or not, there might be other examples also.

Comment: @Aby thanks for the information. I will do more research on this as well...

Comment: @PratikBhat **According to Mahabharata, One day Shiva's wife Parvati, daughter of ...** - where in MahaBharata. Give the Skanda, Chapter, and Verse number.

Comment: @AnuragSingh We are using stackexchange communities from a long time and we know that very well, also requesting you to post comments which are related to the question/answers only. Further reading can be found here about when should one comment and when should one not https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment... thanks

Answer (score 6):

When Lord SadaShiva [directly manifests](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17197/what-happens-to-lord-shivas-trishul-during-dissolution-of-universe/17281#17281) from Sat-Asat state he comes with a form having three eyes:

> परः पुमानीश्वरः स शिव शम्भुरनीश्वरः ।
>   शीर्षे मन्दाकिनीधारी भालचन्द्रस्त्रिलोचनः ।।
>   पञ्चवक्त्र प्रसन्नात्मा दशबाहुस्त्रिशुलधृक् ।
>   कर्पुरगौरः सुसितो भस्मोद्धुलितोविग्रहः ।।
>  
>   Thereafter Parama Purusha Shiva also known as Ishwara having no Lord over him, who holds Mandakini on his head. **He has three eyes and crescent moon on his forehead.** He is five faced, a pleasent soul, holder of a trident, having complexion as white as camphor, keeps on applying white ashes over his body.

So, Lord SadaShiva manifests directly with form of Three-Eyes. It is also stated in [Kaivalya Upanishad:](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/kaivalya.html?lang=sa)

> उमासहायं परमेश्वरं प्रभुं त्रिलोचनं नीलकण्ठं प्रशान्तम् ।
>   ध्यात्वा मुनिर्गच्छति भूतयोनिं समस्तसाक्षिं तमसः परस्तात् ॥ ७॥
>  
>   Meditating on the highest Lord, allied to Uma, powerful, **three-eyed,** blue-necked, and tranquil, the holy man reaches Him who is the source of all, the witness of all and is beyond darkness.

Lord Rudra who is born from Lord Brahma also has three eyes as seen through description of Rudra [in scriptures.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15213/how-many-times-has-shiva-opened-his-3rd-eye/15217#15217) Third Eye of Lord Rudra might be in invisible form also sometimes as seen from [Mahabharata:](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b105.htm)

> The beautiful Uma, with smiling lips and desirous of playing a jest,covered from behind, with her two beautiful hands, the eyes of Mahadeva. As soon as Mahadeva's eyes were thus covered, all the regions became dark and life seemed to be extinct everywhere in the universe. The Homa rites ceased. The universe became suddenly deprived of the sacred Vashat also. All living creatures became cheerless and filled with fear.
>   
>   Indeed, when the eyes of the lord of all creatures were thus closed, the universe seemed to become sunless. Soon, however, that overspreading darkness disappeared. A mighty and blazing flame of fire emanated from Mahadeva's forehead. **A third eye, resembling another sun, appeared (on it). That eye began to blaze forth like the Yuga-fire** and began to consume that mountain. The large-eyed daughter of Himavat, beholding what occurred, bowed her head unto Mahadeva endued with that third eye which resembled a blazing fire.

As Lord has three eyes Lord is also called by the name **Trayambaka** in the Vedas. The significance of name Trayambaka is described in my [**answer here.**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/i-want-to-know-the-exact-explanation-of-maha-mrityunjaya-mantra/18185#18185)

Answer (score 3):

Three eyes represents the three forms or states. From Shiv Rahasya.

> O you who are at peace! Reality or  Truth is Eternally One, without a doubt.  Yet in order to manifest Its Eternal Glory, Truth creates the various Worlds out  of Itself.  Therefore It exists  in different States or Forms. **They  are: Spirit, which is like unto Fire; Energy, which is like unto the Sun; and Matter which is like unto the Moon.** 2.7.

Lord's 3rd eye on forehead represents spirit ( individual consciousness) . And 1st & 2nd eyes energy & matter respectively. This has been confirmed in the same scripture.

> The Lord was wearing a tiger skin, holding in His mighty hands a blazing trident and a drum, and **having the Sun, Moon and Fire as three eyes.** 4.19

Note again,

- Fire is spirit (individual soul) here.
- Sun is energy.
- Moon matter.

Therefore, **Lord Shiva having three eyes means he is holding spirit, energy & matter within himself**. Thus, three eyes represents **Lord Shiva as the ultimate reality**.

This is one case, it is impossible to enumerate all cases in single answer. After few chapters, analogy is changed & **third eye** is explained in different way again as the eye of wisdom.

> The Sleeping Soul is like the Moon  and the Waking Soul like  the Sun. The  Moon which  is the left eye shines by  Night, far off from  the Sun; and when the Sun, the right eye, rises, the Moon is  gone.  **But when  the Fire of Knowledge  which is the Third Eye of Wisdom  burns away both  night  and day, then Sun and  Moon become one and are seen by  no one.**   When neither  Moon nor Sun are seen then the  eye is not two-sided but one.  By  means of that Single Sight  he who is one sees the True Man in the Sky.  He, verily, beholds Truth as It Is. 5.5